# How can I get frame buffer used weston from application side?

Tags: linux, wayland

How can I get frame buffer used weston from application side?

I am developing a program that monitors the frame buffer and detects abnormal operation of the display.

This program is daemon, operating upon Linux (weston)

But I can't find that how can I get frame buffer (raw_data) used weston.

Please give me some advices

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried copying '/dev/fb0' from your application and verifying this buffer? Will it suffice your need?

Comment: Dear SD, my device hasn't /dev/fb0, dev/fb1.

Comment: @SD. This situation, how can I get frame_buffer?